# How to call web service client in java eclipse

Tags: java, android, web-services, web, wsdl

I am developing a android app which invoke cloud service.
I add the web reference client by calling wsdl file `cloudservice.wsdl` in the server site.
it will generate files called

(i)CloudServiceLocator(java file)

(ii)cloudservicesoap(interface)

(iii)CloudServiceSoapProxy(java file)

(iv)CloudServiceSoapStub(java file)

(iV)CloudService(interface)

how can i call the methods inside `CloudServiceSoapStub` class into my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following code after calling the wsdl file

Note:The methods may be changed as per your wsdl service

```
    CloudServiceSoapStub stub=null;
    CloudServiceLocator locator=new CloudServiceLocator();
    String endPointAddress = locator.getServiceSoapAddress();

    try {
        stub=(CloudServiceSoapStub) locator.getServiceSoap(new URL(endPointAddress));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After generating the stub,you can get your required methods

Eg: stub.getValues();

Comment: Try to run this code.but got some errors   NoClassDefFoundError

Comment: Can u provide full log

Comment: 04-28 10:04:39.663: E/AndroidRuntime(7112): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.easylogcloud.www.CloudServiceLocator

Comment: You said you have added the web reference client to your application.The class "CloudServiceLocator' is getting from the web reference only.Check whether you have created the Client properly or not.

Comment: I found the reason we can't call the generated locator and stub class outside the main class.I am using android application unfortunatly android project does not contain main method.Is it possible to add main inside android?.if yes means how to access the main method in android application?

Comment: The purpose of using main method is to call the webservice methods.In android,you can call the web service in "onCreate()" method by creating objects for the webservice classes.

Comment: I want some example coding to call service inside activity oncreate method

Comment: Link1:  https://dzone.com/articles/invoke-webservices-android .          Link2: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr . Try these links

Comment: when i create object for web service classes in Oncreate(). i got NoClassDefFoundError